# Stop blinking wlan light on Ubuntu 9.04?

Tags: ubuntu

I just installed Ubuntu and this is my info:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 9.04
Release:    9.04
Codename:   jaunty
```

And kernel:

```
Linux maxone-laptop 2.6.28-19-generic #66-Ubuntu SMP Sat Oct 16 17:39:04 UTC 2010 i686 GNU/Linux
```

Please if you have solution , my laptop is HP nc8430 . This is driving me crazy.
Thanks

Comment: Why are you still using 9.04? It was released over three years ago and support ended in 2010...

Comment: It is Samurai WTF system based on this Ubuntu details.

Comment: If I recall correctly, a blinking WiFi indicator means that you're connected using Wireless G. Is that the case?